# Is there a way to drag a file from a Web Application to a Desktop Application?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, browser

How programmatically implement a way to drag a local File from a Web Application to a Desktop Application?

Comment: Take a look at the duplicate, maybe you can like display a link to the file like an image and then use OS level drag and drop to get the link to your application and then download the file in the application. Like on windows when you drop a link on the desktop you get a shortcut. Take a look at the duplicate.

Comment: Here is a useful link which should be helpful: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/box_dnd_download/

Answer (score 1):

Check [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations) out. It goes a little bit more into detail. I've created a first version my comment. It drops the link as text (tested in MS Word). Your application now needs to support this kind of drop.

```html
<div 
  draggable="true" 
  ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',
  'http://che.org.il/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pdf-sample.pdf')">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300?text=Placeholder.com+rocks!" draggable="false" />
</div>
```

You may even change the MIME-Type to file or similar and have to adjust the second parameter maybe, I haven't tested this but it's up to your Desktop Application to react to it. [This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) may help you with this but I think you have to download the file first. If thats so I would change the MIME-Type to `application/octet-stream` (for general files), the specific MIME-Type you want or even your own (this way only your application knows it). You can still drop a text / link and then just download the file in your application.

Attempt with MIME-Type etc:

```html
<div 
  draggable="true" 
  ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('application/octet-stream',
  'http://link.to/your/file.txt')">
  <img src="http://repository.wustl.edu/assets/default-c6018ff301250c55bcc663293e1816c7daece4159cbc93fc03d9b35dbc3db30d.png" draggable="false" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You can go the other way of course, but interaction with locally installed applications requires you to access (download) the remote file first.

Comment: This is not a 100% true, if you drag a link to a file (which can be display like an image of a file) you can drag "the image" to the desktop application and then download the file yourself.

Comment: I know what you are saying but the reality is that this functionality is primarily limited to images and therefore would be a hack, so naming a file my_excel_workbook.png would work, but you really wanna do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to start a download of any image that is dragged on screen. Not at all sure if this is what you want, but it just kind of backs up what Wernerson commented.

```js
document.addEventListener('drag', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'IMG') {
     var src = e.target.src;
     var a = document.createElement('a');
     a.setAttribute('download', '');
     a.setAttribute('href', src);
     a.click();
  }
})
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300?text=Placeholder.com+rocks!">
```